Как добавить тело к http ответу 401 в Helidon SE4
Задача: Есть REST сервис написанный с использованием фреймворка Helidon SE4. Аутентификация реализованна через библиотеку helidon-security. В случае, если пользователь не прошел аутентификацию, необходимо вернуть ему детальное сообщение об ошибке.
Проблема: По умолчанию возвращается ответ с кодом 401 и пустым телом.
Как я пробовал решить проблему: Я реализовал AuthenticationProvider и пробовал вернуть сообщение пользователю через AuthenticationResponse.  Сообщение я добавлял через метод authenticationResponse.description(String description). Но любые данные добавляемые через этот метод просто игнорируются. Других способов передать информацию пользователю о деталях неудачной аутентификации я не нашел.
Вопрос: Как в Helidon SE4 кастомизировать http ответ 401 используя библиотеку helidon-security? Правильный ли я вообще выбрал подход?
